# Windows Shell Batch Script to copy the last 10 modified files

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to create a Script to copy from a Directory the last 10 modified files.

I'm trying with this code:

```
for /F %%I IN ('DIR *.* /B /A:-D-H /O:-D') do (
  copy /Y %%I C:\DestinationDir
)
```

This code copy ALL of them, how can I stop the "for" after 10th iteration?

====================

Second try to solve this.

I tried splitting it in two scripts, but "exit /b" (or only "exit") finish all the batch process:

FirstScript, the same code but trying to exit after copying the newest file:

```
for /F %%I IN ('DIR *.* /B /A:-D-H /O:-D') do (
  copy /Y %%I C:\DestinationDir
  exit /b
)
```

SecondScript, that loops 10 times calling the FirstScript:

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 10) do (
   FirstScript.bat
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('dir /o-d /a-d-h /b * ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
    if %%a gtr 10 goto done
    copy /y "%%b" c:\destinationDir
)
:done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant that works without delayed expansion and without using FIND or FINDSTR. I conditionally exit the loop when I intentionally divide by zero.

```
set cnt=10
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /o-d /a-d-h /b') do (
  copy /y "%%F" c:\destinationDir
  2>nul set /a 1/(cnt-=1) || goto :break
)
:break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set cnt=0
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=[]" %%b in (
'dir /b /a-d-h /o-d^|find /n /v ""') do (
  set /a cnt+=1
  if !cnt! LEQ 10 echo copy /y "%%c" "c:\DestinationDir"
)
```

remove the echo when you see desired results.

Comment: Why prefix each file with a line number if you don't use it?

Comment: @dbenham - I just had it in there when I was doing some testing and forgot to take it out.